# Wrong type of smart contract being instantiated on using new keyword

Tags: solidity, remix, truffle, contract-deployment

I have 2 smart contracts **A** and **B** that I have defined in the same file.

**B** is used to instantiate **A** using the `new` keyword.

However, when I try to interact on Remix with the newly instantiated contract using its returned address, I see the type of the newly instantiated contract is actually **B** and not **A**.

Why is this happening?

As, the two contracts are defined in the same file so **B** should have the byte code for **A**. Right?

Also, the `constructor` for **A** is public, so I don't understand why the new contract is of type **B**, when it should be of type **A**.

```js
//patient is analogous to A

contract patient is entity{
    mapping (string => address) patientIDToSC;

    constructor (address adr, string memory idname) public {
        id = idname;
        ethAddress = adr;
        entityType = "patient";
        RCAddress = RC3(msg.sender);
    }
    //other relevant functions
}

//RC3 is analogous to B

contract RC3{
    address payable owner;
    constructor(){
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }
    mapping(string => address) public entityIDToEthAddress;
    mapping(address => address) public ethAddressToContractAddress;

    function insertEntity(string memory name, uint entityType) public payable{
        if(entityType == 0){
            patient newPatientSmartContract;
            newPatientSmartContract = new patient(msg.sender, name);
            ethAddressToContractAddress[msg.sender] = address(newPatientSmartContract);
        }
    }
    //other relevant code
}
```

The problem is whenever I try calling `insertEntity` in **RC3**, instead of creating a **patient** contract, it creates another contract of **RC3** type, or at least that's what it shows on Remix. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to this line:

```js
newPatientSmartContract = new patient(msg.sender, name);
```

Then, indeed it's creating a new **patient** contract, not **RC3**.

The same can be confirmed by invoking the public variables of **patient** contract using the `newPatientSmartContract` instance and storing the values of the same in the corresponding variables of **RC3** contract, inside the `insertEntity()` function call, like:

```js
idInRC3 = newPatientSmartContract.id();
entityTypeInRC3 = newPatientSmartContract.entityType();
```

When you check the values of `idInRC3` and `entityTypeInRC3`, then they'll be having the exact same values that are being assigned to `id` and `entityType` in the `constructor` of **patient** contract.

As, the value of `idInRC3` will be whatever being passed in the `name` param of `insertEntity()` (that will be further passed as the `idname` param in the `constructor` of **patient** contract).

And, the value of `entityTypeInRC3` will be assigned as `"patient"` string (i.e., the exact same as what's being assigned to `entityType` in the `constructor` of **patient** contract).

The minimal code to test the same is:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

//patient is analogous to A

contract patient {
    mapping (string => address) patientIDToSC;
    string public id;
    address ethAddress;
    string public entityType;
    RC3 RCAddress;

    constructor (address adr, string memory idname) {
        id = idname;
        ethAddress = adr;
        entityType = "patient";
        RCAddress = RC3(msg.sender);
    }
    //other relevant functions
}

//RC3 is analogous to B

contract RC3{
    address payable owner;
    string public idInRC3;
    string public entityTypeInRC3;

    constructor(){
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }
    mapping(string => address) public entityIDToEthAddress;
    mapping(address => address) public ethAddressToContractAddress;

    function insertEntity(string memory name, uint entityType) public payable{
        if(entityType == 0){
            patient newPatientSmartContract;
            newPatientSmartContract = new patient(msg.sender, name);
            ethAddressToContractAddress[msg.sender] = address(newPatientSmartContract);
            idInRC3 = newPatientSmartContract.id();
            entityTypeInRC3 = newPatientSmartContract.entityType();
        }
    }
    //other relevant code
}
```

P.S., You don't need to add the `public` visibility to the `constructor`, as **constructors** are `public` by default.